# Demonstration in hilbert system

Tags: logic

I have the following logic framework :
proofs are list of formulas, consisting of instance of axioms, or cut.
The axioms are the following :

$$X_1 \to  (X_2 \to  X_1) \tag{A1}$$
$$(X_1 \to  (X_2 \to  X_3)) \to  ((X_1 \to  X_2) \to  (X_1 \to  X_3)) \tag{A2}$$
$$X_1 \to  \lnot \lnot X_1 \tag{A3}$$
$$(\lnot \lnot X_1) \to  X_1 \tag{A4}$$
$$(X_1 \to  X_2) \to  ((\lnot X_2) \to  \lnot X_1) \tag{A5}$$
$$X_1 \to  (X_2 \to  (X_1 \land  X_2)) \tag{A6}$$
$$(X_1 \land  X_2) \to  X_1 \tag{A7}$$
$$(X_1 \land  X_2) \to  X_2 \tag{A8}$$
$$X_1 \to  (X_1 \lor  X_2) \tag{A9}$$
$$X_2 \to  (X_1 \lor  X_2) \tag{A10}$$
$$(\lnot X_1) \to  ((X_1 \lor  X_2) \to  X_2) \tag{A11}$$

I want to prove $$(A\to B)\to ((C\lor A) \to (C\lor B))$$

Does anybody know a framework able to derive such demonstrations ?

Comment: A good starting point will be to use Ax.1 and Ax.2 to prove $X \to X$ and use them to prove the Deduction Theorem. Also $X \to Y, Y \to Z \vdash X \to Z$ will be useful.

Comment: Where does this strange system of axioms come from?

Comment: It comes from the P. Dehornoy book on set theory

Comment: The 'cut' rule is Modus Ponens?

Comment: Did the book already prove the Deduction Theorem? Can you use it?

Comment: What a nasty system!!!   Even proving $P \lor \neg P$ is a pain .... Does the book do some proofs already?  And again, can you use some of those earlier proven results?

Comment: @Bram28 To get a taste, i have some demonstrations in my unit tests. This one is in https://github.com/Sylvain78/Preuves/blob/master/prop/test/test_formula_prop.ml#L83

Comment: @Sylvain Yikes .. that's really not digestible for me. I can't even tell if these are proofs or just a bunch of statements.